# Does imidazole and hydrochloric acid yield imidazole hydrochloride salt?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds

I'm asking this because I found a [link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/core-bioreagents/biological-buffers/learning-center/buffer-reference-center.html) for imidazole-HCl buffer: , but from what I understand, a buffer is a weak acid or base with its corresponding salt. Would imidazole-HCl buffer be a salt solution, or does it have a weak acid or base as well (if it does, what is the weak acid/base)? Also, I found two different pictures for imidazole hydrochloride:
[image]
[image]
Which one is correct? Is imidazole-HCl a salt or a buffer?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Nice question, BTW!

Answer (score 4):

[image: Imidazole hydrochloride]

The correct structure of the salt is as shown above. This structure is more stable than the one that has two hydrogens on the same nitrogen - due to electron delocalization.

If you have a water solution of about 50/50 imidazole base and the hydrochloride salt, you get the maximum buffer capacity, due to the fact that both acid and base forms are present, and a small amount of a strong acid or base subsequently added to the mixture will react with these imidazole species, and therefore have little effect on the pH.

Comment: It may be worth adding that since the lone pair in the other nitrogen is a part of the pi-cloud (aromatic sextet) and therefore the basicity of this nitrogen would be low.